# on click duplicate an image on the same row

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a row of images on click but they are showing up after the div tag at the botom of my page, is the document.body.innerHTML making it do that?

```
     flowers = 1;

     function makeFlower() {

        if (flowers < 10 ){document.body.innerHTML +="<img src='flower.jpg'>";
        flowers ++;
            }
}


<p> Make a happy garden by clicking the flower many times! </p>
    <p><img src="flower.jpg"
            onClick="makeFlower()">
            </p>
```

Comment: You are appending your site body. What did u expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

By using `document.body.innerHTML +=` (the `+=` is important) you are appending content to the body of your document.

You should add an `id` (attribute) to the paragraph that contains the image:

```
<p id="garden">
    <img src="flower.jpg" onClick="makeFlower()">
</p>
```

Now you can target `garden` with `document.getElementById("garden")`:

```
flowers = 1;
function makeFlower() {

    if (flowers < 10 ) {

        document.getElementById("garden").innerHTML +="<img src='flower.jpg'>";

        flowers ++;
    }
}
```

This will get you started.

Comment: This is the right answer. I was working up a fiddle while you were responding in case OP would like a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jhb6L/

Comment: thanks so much, I tried an id but I put it in the wrong place at first